# SQL query does not return data

Tags: abap, opensql

I am developing a SAP program to obtain information about a reference from the material table (`MARA`).

First I take certain references and then using a loop I need to make other query for every iteration:

```
SELECT
  MARA~BISMT
FROM mara
WHERE mara~matnr = @ref
INTO @var.
```

I know that the problem is that the types conflict (`mara~matnr` is characters and `ref` is string), how can I convert both to the same type and see the results?

Comment: I think that you're talking about external (`ref`) and internal values (`mara~matnr`), you go from one value to the other via [conversion routines](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconversion_exits.htm), either with function module `RS_CONV_EX_2_IN` or with statement `WRITE` (internal to external).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use field symbol for dynamic type and `CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT` function module for formatting value for db.

```
TABLES: mara.

DATA: ref TYPE string,
      var TYPE string.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_ref> TYPE any.

ref = '11'.

ASSIGN ('mara-matnr') TO <fs_ref>.
CHECK sy-subrc IS INITIAL.

<fs_ref> = ref.

CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
  EXPORTING
    input   = <fs_ref>
 IMPORTING
   output   = <fs_ref>.


SELECT SINGLE mara~bismt
  FROM mara
  INTO @var
 WHERE mara~matnr = @<fs_ref>.
```

Comment: TABLES statement is obsolete and throws syntax error inside classes, it shouldn't be used

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [ABAP string templates](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenstring_template_alpha_abexa.htm) instead of conversion exits suggested by mkysoft:

```
DATA: ref TYPE string VALUE '2'.

ref = |{ CONV matnr( ref ) ALPHA = in  }|.

SELECT SINGLE bismt
  FROM mara
 WHERE matnr = @ref
  INTO @DATA(var).
```