# Query for apha field using string literal

Tags: abap, opensql

How can I use string literal to query tables if the raw value in the table is different from the value I use in the string literal?

I made a Z table that uses `MATNR` and 2 other fields as primary keys. In a dummy programm I filled the table with 4 rows using this code

```
delete from z_test_db.
data ls_tab type z_test_db.
data now type timestamp.

get time stamp field now.
ls_tab = value #( matnr = '4711' vorne = 0010 terminal = 'AAA' etkpgm = 'XXX' drucker = 'MO-ED-01' voretkm = 1 etkcopy = 1 eruser = sy-uname ertime = now aeuser = '' aetime = 0 kzaktv = 'X' kzaaeu = '' kzaaet = 0 ).
insert z_test_db from ls_tab.

get time stamp field now.
ls_tab = value #( matnr = '4712' vorne = 0010 terminal = 'AAA' etkpgm = 'XXX' drucker = 'MO-ED-01' voretkm = 1 etkcopy = 1 eruser = sy-uname ertime = now aeuser = '' aetime = 0 kzaktv = 'X' kzaaeu = '' kzaaet = 0 ).
insert z_test_db from ls_tab.

get time stamp field now.
ls_tab = value #( matnr = '4711' vorne = 0010 terminal = 'BBB' etkpgm = 'XXX' drucker = 'MO-ED-01' voretkm = 1 etkcopy = 1 eruser = sy-uname ertime = now aeuser = '' aetime = 0 kzaktv = 'X' kzaaeu = '' kzaaet = 0 ).
insert z_test_db from ls_tab.

get time stamp field now.
ls_tab = value #( matnr = '4712' vorne = 0010 terminal = 'BBB' etkpgm = 'XXX' drucker = 'MO-ED-01' voretkm = 1 etkcopy = 1 eruser = sy-uname ertime = now aeuser = '' aetime = 0 kzaktv = 'X' kzaaeu = '' kzaaet = 0 ).
insert z_test_db from ls_tab.
```

to create some dummy rows.

When I query that table for `MATNR = '4711'` it works but as soon as I use that value to query MARA there are no rows returned. I found out this is due to how MARA stores the value internally. If I open MARA in `SE16N` I can see that the value looks like `'000000000000004711'` in raw but gets displayed as `'4711'` to the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query does not return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541853/sql-query-does-not-return-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain `MATNR` uses the conversion routine `MATN1` and it works like this:

#### Input value from screen to DB

If you input the field from a screen (eg: MM01) the function `CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_INPUT` is automatically applied before writing in DB converting `4711` into `000000000000004711`

#### Output value from DB to screen

When the `MATNR` field is read from DB and displayed on the screen, the function `CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_OUTPUT` is called automatically, showing the value `4711` instead of the internal format `000000000000004711`

In short: `MATNR` is shown as `4711` on screen but the DB table is written with `000000000000004711`

#### In your case

you're inserting in DB the value `4711` without using the `MATN1` routine. For this reason you are not finding the value in `MARA`:
values `4711` in `Z_TEST_DB` and `000000000000004711` in `MARA` don't match.

Try fix the code with:

```
data lv_matnr type matnr.

ls_tab = value #( matnr = '4711' vorne = 0010 terminal = 'AAA' etkpgm = 'XXX' drucker = 'MO-ED-01' voretkm = 1 etkcopy = 1 eruser = sy-uname ertime = now aeuser = '' aetime = 0 kzaktv = 'X' kzaaeu = '' kzaaet = 0 ).

call function 'CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_INPUT'
  exporting
    input        = ls_tab-matnr
  importing
    output       = ls_tab-matnr
  exceptions
    length_error = 1
    others       = 2.
```

This converts the `MATNR` into `000000000000004711` and you'll find the link with `MARA`.